Way to perform a numpy "argany" or "argfirst"?
I'd like to reduce a multidimensional array along one axis by finding the first value in the other dims that is truthy/matches some condition, or a default value if no matching elements can be found. So far I'm trying to do this for a 3D array with some simple looping as follows:
def first(arr, condition, default):
    out = default.copy()

    for u in range(arr.shape[1]):
        for e in range(arr.shape[2]):
            (idx,) = np.nonzero(condition[:, u, e])
            if len(idx):
                out[u, e] = arr[idx[0], u, e]

    return out

This is a bit ugly, not efficient, not vectorized, and not easily generalized to arrays of arbitrary dims though. Does numpy have a nicer, built-in way to achieve this?
EDIT:
Here's an example case:
test_arr = np.array(
    [
        [np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, np.nan],
        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
        np.full((10,), np.nan),
    ]
)

test_default = np.array([5, 5, 5, 5])
test_cond = ~np.isnan(test_arr)

Expected Output:
first(test_arr, test_cond, test_default)
# outputs [1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0]


Can you give some examples arrays for testing?

Make your first work with those test arrays.

Numpy does not as far as I know have a builtin way to achieve this. But how about:
import numpy as np

# Setup:
H, W, D = 4, 6, 5

arr = np.random.rand(H, W, D)
condition = np.random.rand(H, W, D) < 0.1
default = np.random.rand(W, D)

axis = 0

# Proposed solution:
# 1. Use `np.argmax` to find the indices of the first
#    truthy element in `condition`.
# 2. Use `np.take_along_axis` with that result to extract
#    the values at those indices from `arr`.
values = np.take_along_axis(
    arr,
    np.argmax(condition, axis=axis, keepdims=True),
    axis=axis
)

# Problem is that `np.argmax` will return 0
# for all subarrays in `condition` that are all falsy.
# So we finally filter between the (squeezed) `values`
# and `default` using `np.where`.
out = np.where(
    np.any(condition, axis=axis),
    np.squeeze(values, axis=axis),
    default
)


I would divide the plan into these steps :
1- Create a mask that identifies where the condition is met.
2- Find the indices of the first occurrence of the condition being met along the specified axis.
3- Use these indices to gather the corresponding elements from the original array.
I would try something like this :
import numpy as np

def first(arr, condition, default):
    # Create a mask where the condition is met
    mask = condition(arr)
    
    # Initialize the output array with the default value
    out = np.full(arr.shape[1:], default)
    
    # Find the indices of the first occurrence of the condition being met along axis 0
    idx = np.argmax(mask, axis=0)
    
    # Create a mask to identify where no condition is met
    no_condition_met = ~mask.any(axis=0)
    
    # Use advanced indexing to gather the first occurrence where the condition is met
    out[~no_condition_met] = arr[idx[~no_condition_met], np.arange(arr.shape[1])[:, None], np.arange(arr.shape[2])]
    
    return out

# Example usage
arr = np.random.rand(4, 3, 3)
condition = lambda x: x > 0.5
default = -1

result = first(arr, condition, default)
print(result)

